# Hearing Aids During Shabbat- Sleeping

Tags: shabbat, technology, how-to, handicap-disabled-impair, hearing

It seems to be accepted that a hearing aid should be turned on before Shabbat. Out of curiosity, how do people practically manage having their hearing aids left on when they are sleeping in a household of hearing people? Typically, hearing aids are removed for sleeping. However, there would be feedback from the hearing aids that can affect the sleep of everyone else. I’ve never been frum, but I was curious about this. I accidentally left a hearing aid on but took it out before a dinner (left it on a counter), and everyone else was going crazy trying to figure out what the annoying sound was. Without the hearing aids, it would be hard to connect and fully participate in Shabbat. With the hearing aids, you might affect everyone else’s sanity/Shabbat. Just wondered if anyone had any practical experience. Are the hearing aids somehow plugged or put in a well-sealed box while sleeping? Maybe even put outside?

Comment: Welcome to MiYodeya Eva and thanks for this first question. Since MY is different from other sites you might be used to, see [here](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501) for a guide which might help understand the site. Great to have you learn with us!

Comment: Is this a Judaism question? I'm not sure.